# Methods with different signatures in Typescript class inheritence

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

could someone explain why the following code snippet will introduce error please? Thank you!

```
class Base {
  greet() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
}
 
class Derived extends Base {
  // Make this parameter required
  greet(name: string) { // why we have error here?
    console.log(`Hello, ${name.toUpperCase()}`);
  }
}
```

```
const b: Base = new Derived();
b.greet(); // why it crashes here?
```

I use Java a lot. So maybe I am thinking in a JAVA way. From my understanding, Derived class inherits great() method in Base class. When it defines greet(name: string) method, this method should be treated as method overloading. So Derived class should have both greet() and greet(name: string). Why we have error here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Comment: TS compiles to JS, which is not Java.  In JS, `b.greet` refers to a single function object. JS has no built in mechanism to dispatch a method call to different function objects based on parameters.  If you want to see such behavior, you'll have to implement it [manually like this](https://tsplay.dev/NnQB6w).

Answer (score 3):

Consider this simple example:

```js
type EmptyGreet = () => void

type FullGreed = (arg: string) => void

let emptyGreed: EmptyGreet = () => { }
let fullGreed: FullGreed = (arg: string) => arg.toLowerCase()

emptyGreed = fullGreed // error
emptyGreed() // ok, but there is runtime error

fullGreed = emptyGreed // ok
fullGreed('hello') // ok, hello argument does not have any impact on business logic
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAjxRW)

As you might have noticed, it is unsafe to assign function with argument to the function without argument.

Same is here:

```js
class Base {
  greet() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
}
 
class Derived extends Base {
  // Make this parameter required
  greet(name: string) { // why we have error here?
    console.log(`Hello, ${name.toUpperCase()}`);
  }
}

const b: Base = new Derived();
b.greet(); // why it crashes here?
```

class `Derived` expects an argument for `greet` method and you are trying to call `greet` without such argument. This is why TS does not allow you to use explicit type `Base` for `b` const

> this method should be treated as method overloading ...

This is not true. This is not how method overloading works in typescript.

```js
class Foo {
    foo(arg: string): string
    foo(arg: number): number
    foo(arg: any) {
        return null as any
    }
}
```

P.S. Please consider using keyword `override` ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#override-and-the---noimplicitoverride-flag)) if you want to override a method

Comment: And after reading that... stay away from it...!!! :-)